# OOP in Svelte and its reactivity

Tags: oop, svelte, sveltekit

I wanna use svelte for a little app that Im making. The app was half finished using plain html/css/js when I stumbled upon Svelte.
I was using a lot of javascript classes and aimed for object oriented programming.

Now looking at svelte, it looks like its not made for OOP at all. Am I wrong? Properties of classes wont be tracked and updated by svelte.

Maybe my approach is wrong. I basicly used a View/Model pattern, where I have a model class object that Im feeding the svelte component. Using the object's properties in html wont update obviously. (This works great with angular i.e.)

```
<script lang="ts">

    import type { Key } from "../key";

    export let key: Key

    const onTrigger = () => {
        key.trigger()
    }
    const onRelease = () => {
        key.release()
    }

</script>


<div
    class="key" 
    class:black={key.note[1] == '#' || key.note[1] === 'b'}
    class:pressed={key.isPressed} 
    on:pointerdown={onTrigger} 
    on:pointerup={onRelease} 
    on:pointerleave={onRelease}
    style={key.isPressed ? 'transform: scale(1.5); transform-origin: center;' : ''}>
    
  <div class="key-mapping">{@html key.mapping.toLocaleUpperCase() + '<br/>' }</div>
  <div class="key-note">{ key.note + (key.octave ? key.octave.toString() : '') }</div>
</div>
```

(Key represents a piano key sitting inside a piano component, things like `key.isPressed` or `key.octave` wont update, because they are changed in the model class)

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/c06513d17083419f8ab6eb685861aecb?version=3.53.1)

I really dont wanna use the store for ALL properties of my classes that I use in html, because I think this is not the purpose of the store. I was hoping to save some code by using Svelte and not make it weird and complex.

I saw the trick to reassign the whole object like this

```
object.property = 'some value'
object = object
```

to trigger reactivity, but this wont work when changing the properties outside of the component.

Also using the reactive marking `$: { ... }` I wasnt able to update any class' property (Only when changing it directly from a html event)

Also saw a decorator function to make classes reactive to svelte, but the decorator makes the class singleton too, which makes it useless to me.

So there are a few questions I wanna ask:

1. Is there any proper way to update class properties in Svelte?
2. If not, whats the prefered coding style? Functional?
3. Will there be OOP support in the future?

Comment: Svelte has a page on reactive objects: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects. Can you show your code where this isn't working? BTW Svelte itself IS object-oriented, maybe you are trying to use classes as data?

Comment: Hey, what do you mean with using a class as data? A class is structured, reusable data, isnt it? I gave a example above on how I use my class. Here I made a REPL to demonstrate the same simpified. Text should change color on hover. Check console too. https://svelte.dev/repl/c06513d17083419f8ab6eb685861aecb?version=3.53.1

Comment: I believe you could achieve this by making your Key class/controller into a [Svelte store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store), then subscribing to that store in your component. Each key would have to be a store instance that would keep track of that key's state. Changes to the state of a key in the store would be instantly reflected to all components subscribed to that store.

Comment: @ThomasHennes Do you mean making the whole class instance a store? Like so ```const key = writable(new Key(...))``` ? Ill give it a try

Comment: Yes, exactly. Stores can be easily customized, so you could add methods like `onTrigger`, `onRelease` etc. that update the store internally, keeping values like `isPressed` or `octave` up to date.

Comment: The store design itself is left up to you. You can either have one instance of a large `Keys` store where all keys' states are monitored simultaneously, or an array of `Key` instances that each monitor a single key. In both cases, you'd want to initialize your store(s) when the app is initially loaded.

Comment: You will probably want to look into [custom stores](https://fireship.io/snippets/custom-svelte-stores/), which can be incredibly helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i first need to dig more into stores. Youre first comment confuses me a bit. Do you mean to make a store that kinda merges the key class and store into one? By adding functions like onTrigger to the store? But why? I actually like having view and ctrl seperated. Ctrl should work without the view.

Comment: Thanks, i will check out custom stores, tho I wonder that there is no official (and documented) way of using classes in svelte. My questions persist

Comment: Just to clarify my first comment, most web projects distinguish between classes and data. A class is a component in your site that not only contains a state but also functionality (methods). But for many websites, the data itself does not need to be a class and is formatted as JSON (by which I mean a structure of arrays and objects). The data does not have methods so does not need to be a class. There CAN be a class that manages the data (a store, as mentioned above).

Comment: @Kokodoko I wanna know about OOP Classes in Svelte and how to update view when a class property changes. I know that my components are classes too, but I have libraries I use and they use real js Class'es.

Comment: Then maybe you  could include an example of that library where your data is in a class. The question then becomes how to integrate that library into Svelte.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dummy assignments as soon as you assign to a property (rather than invoking a method) and there is no issue with using classes as long as you do not "hide" changes from Svelte's compiler.

E.g. this will work just fine (inside the component):

```js
const onTrigger = () => {
    key.isPressed = true;
}
const onRelease = () => {
    key.isPressed = false;
}
```

In general your components should be fairly specialized so they do not have to deal with deeply nested data and complex modifications which makes it easy to lose reactivity.

Ideally you just have some very simple local state via component properties rather than objects. Here your `Key` component should just use properties for all its state e.g. `isPressed` should just be a property that then can be bound on the level of the parent component.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you mean, but I learned web dev differently. Im used to MVC. What if my Key is triggering a synthesizer from tonejs. It consists of many nested classes. While listening to the sound I want to display data which is held in the tonejs classes (Oscillator, filters, envelope etc.). That code is hidden away anyway, for good reason. View's shouldnt have controller logic. Also it makes it really difficult to work with libraries. Really dont see how to work properly with this approach. So much code would go into the components. Am i wrong?

Comment: Well, the components should contain logic that is relevant to view state. Any state that is not relevant for that can be encapsulated and hidden without problem. You just have to separate data and logic. Components contain the logic for their little domain, and data (without logic) is passed between the components via their properties. Integrating libraries should not be difficult, it all comes down to handling events and updating component state accordingly. Components can communicate via events as well, if necessary.

Comment: Therefore I need to make a top level variable of every variable that is hidden inside a class (isPressed is used internally too), and update them in both directions? Libraries are mostly classes with hidden code. how do you display a tonejs' synth variables for example (without a store)? Any article or example would be great

Comment: You have to get rid of the "used internally", as I said, separate logic from data, otherwise you will lose reactivity. You don't necessarily need individual properties for everything, it depends on what things change and where the changes have to propagate. If you e.g. need `isPressed` outside the `Key` component, then passing in the entire key as an object will not allow you to observe changes to `isPressed` on the outside (unless you fire events). You should not try to never use stores. Especially for third party code like libraries they can be very useful to build a reactive facade.

Comment: I don't know `tonejs`, for something like sound, it might be best to use a polling/`requestAnimationFrame` approach for updating the UI in real time.

Comment: I appreaciate your help, thanks. So basicly I do need to make a top level variable of every variable that is hidden inside a class and is displayed in a view and then update it via events/timeouts/intervals/etc like you have shown above? I was trying to pass down single properties of the class instead of the whole class instance, same thing tho.

Comment: Yes, if the properties are going to change, that is a good approach. E.g. if I have a component for editing a user i might have properties for `name`, `birthday` etc. and bind them all, but if I am just displaying that (and the data is not modified anywhere at the same time) i tend to have a component `UserDisplay` that just gets passed a single property `user` whose relevant properties can then be read and shown without having to worry about reactivity.